# When I select year in dropdown list the years are getting repeated after selecting why?

Tags: magento-1.8

I had created the date of birth field with a drop down list after selecting the year drop down the years are getting repeated

I am attaching my code and image file.

Can u please suggest me.

Answer (score 2):

Regardless how you populate your select options, just need to add class `validate-select` to any `<select>` element you want to validate.

`validate-select` requires user to select an option.

In your case, change `validate-entry` to `validate-select`, then it works.

Comment: I changed the code as you suggested but not working.It is not asking is required when i click on the generate button it is directly going to another page with null data.Please suggest me

Comment: while developing, please turn off any cache solution, even pagespeed. I see your form code `var dataForm = new VarienForm('form-custom-search', true);` doesn't excute at all.

Comment: Yes,I changed now it works fine but when i select year 2005 or any number it is showing repeated years after selecting.I am attaching the image.Please suggest me.

Comment: Remove this code and all js code following it `kcyear.addEventListener("change", validate_date);` also remove `onchange=call()` in `<select>`.

Comment: If i remove those it will not load day and year then how can i overcome this issue

Comment: keep removing javascript code, then instead removing `onchange=call()`, chang to `onload=call();`
This is a hotfix. Better you should wrap it on dom:load event, but it requires you some further research. Take your time.

Answer (score 0):

You only added `class="required"` to the `<label>`. This way you get a red <kbd>*</kbd> next to the label, nothing more, nothing less. Look at the `<select>` element for gender to see how it is done.

Comment: I added the class to select element for date of birth field also but it getting same error for me.When i click on the generate button it is not asking is required directly it is going to new page without filling the form.